# Winding of $\frac{\zeta(\sigma+it)}{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+it)}$ for $0 \lt \sigma \le \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

The image of the imaginary-positive critical line $\frac{1}{2}+it, t \ge 0$ in the function $ዘ(z) = \frac{\zeta(z)}{\zeta^{\prime}(z)}$ (i.e. the reciprocal of the logarithmic derivative of $\zeta$) is a surprisingly neat spiral tangent to the imaginary axis at $0$ for values of $t$ corresponding to nontrivial zeros:

[[image: <span class=]$\sigma={1\over 2}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvgTq.png)

This spiral is continuous and always winds counterclockwise.

For $0 < \sigma < {1\over 2}$ the spiral is less neat and self-intersects wildly, but it also seems to remain continuous (i.e. no loops seem to be pulled apart to infinity) and CCW-winding (i.e. no dimples or cusps appear in loops) ($\sigma=0.3$):

[[image: <span class=]$\sigma={3\over 10}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feUlp.png)

Is it known to be true? If the truth of this conjecture ("loop conservation") is unknown, is it known to either imply or follow from RH?

EDIT: this "loop through $0$, tangent to the imaginary axis" behavior is not specific to $\zeta \over {\zeta^\prime}$. It is a universal property of $f \over {f^\prime}$ for any complex-differentiable $f$: the image in $f \over {f^\prime}$ of a small segment through a zero of $f$ is an arc through the origin, with the tangent at the origin parallel to the segment.

I was aware of this general fact when writing my question, but I was unaware of another fact that I only realized just now: this works for zeros of any multiplicity! $f \over {f^\prime}$ does *not* do what $f$ does, i.e. fly through $0$ at odd zeros and bounce from $0$ at even zeros. It *always* flies through $0$ at zeros of $f$. In fact, the (limit of) the *derivative* of $f \over {f^\prime}$ at a zero of $f$ is identically equal to the real number $1 \over m$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of the zero. This derivative being real makes sure that the arc at $0$ is parallel to the segment.

The purpose of this long edit is to point out that the basic "looping" behavior of $ዘ(\sigma + it)$ probably isn't "ruined" by non-simple zeros (at least not directly).

Comment: Is this not equivalent to the conjecture that the nontrivial Riemann zeta zero's all have multiplicity $1$ ?

Comment: Is that a conjecture? I thought that it was proven. Or was it proven only for the nontrivial zeros on the critical line (i.e. RH non-counterexamples?)

Comment: My interest in "loop conservation" in the left half of the critical strip is because it implies a particular connectedness: if there are no discontiuities or inflection points for any $0 \lt \sigma \lt {1\over 2}$, then any off-critical nontrivial zero must be paired with an on-critical nontrivial zero on the same loop, i.e. as the "scan line" moves to the left from the critical line, one _specific_ rightmost point of one _specific_ loop must get _back_ to $0$, and loop/winding conservation would prevent this return to origin from happening through other curve gymnastics.

Comment: It is an open conjecture for all nonreal zero's of the Riemann zeta function. So both on or off the critical line.

Comment: @mick I don't think the basic looping behavior would be ruined by multiple zeros. See my edit.

Comment: oh yes the log derivative. I see. sorry you are right. But then what remains of your question ?

Comment: I'll leave it open for now, but cusps are irrelevant, and the only RH killer can be a loop going around $\infty$ (i.e. a zero of $\zeta^\prime$ in LHCS - open problem). That's b.c. for $\sigma={1\over 2}$ all loops past 1st zero sit in the closed left half-plane (known property) and will initially move to the left as we decrease $\sigma$ b.c. $ዘ^\prime$ is real$_+$ at zeros of $\zeta$, but for the same reason the arc sweeping the origin while we scan past an RH-violating zero would have to sweep it right to left - and the only way it can _get_ to the right of the origin is around $\infty$.

Comment: of interest may be Speiser criterion for RH proved (at least roughly) by Speiser and quantitatively (relating the number of zeroes of $\zeta$ and $\zeta'$ in $0<\sigma <1/2$) by Levinson and Montgomery, namely that RH is equivalent to $\zeta'$ having no zeroes for $0< \sigma <1/2$